# "Run-time error '-2147221040 (800401d0)' happen sometimes after excel upgrade from 2010 to 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I used VBA to generate the pictures before and the code is shown below, it never happened any error. But when I upgraded the Micro-Soft office version from 2010 to 2016, it happens

> "Run-time error '-2147221040 (800401d0)'

[image: 1]

occasionally, and it will ok if i try to re-run the same macro. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks in advance~~

```
Sub Chart_generate()
    
    Dim j As Byte
    Dim Max As Byte
    Dim TOOL As String
    Dim WCpath As String
    
    Sheets("pivot").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh

    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 130
    Max = Range("AO1")
    For j = 2 To Max + 1
        TOOL = Range("AN" & j)
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("TOOL").CurrentPage = TOOL
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart1").Activate
        WCpath = "D:\users\Picture\" & TOOL & "_Pressure.png"
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
        ActiveChart.Export (WCpath)
    Next j 
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
    Range("A2").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know which line it's throwing that error message on?  I assume it's ActiveChart.Export (WCpath) but I'd like to be sure.

Comment: Yes, this error happens after " ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select " and before " ActiveChart.Export (WCpath)"

Comment: Are you sure ChartArea isn't null?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue when moving graphs generated on hidden worksheets over to a visible worksheet, and then resizing them.

My code is repeated multiple times in a large loop (not seen in code below), and it works more often than not but will periodically fail. If I use the debugger and single step it always works perfectly; it's only a problem when running full speed.

I've tried solutions from the web including `DoEvents` and the `On Error` tricks. I added a `While` loop and some verbal feedback to help identify the code causing the problem.

I hear "runtime 2" more often than "runtime 1". It always works fault-free single stepping in the debugger, but fails occasionally on some computers. During a fail, if I click on the pictures, the name of the object doesn't appear in the upper left box of the worksheet where it normally would.

Of the eleven machines tested, I've seen problems on three of them. Mine works better than most, which is a problem for a code developer!

histogram second

```
Sheets("Histogram").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("pi_Histogram")).Select
DoEvents

On Error Resume Next
errflag = 0
Selection.Copy
While Err.Number = 1004 And errflag < 10
    Err.Number = 0
    Application.Speech.Speak "runtime 1"
    Selection.Copy
    errflag = errflag + 1
Wend

Sheets("Raw Data").Select
Range("V23").Select     'start insertion point for coefficients table
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 10 + segment).Select
DoEvents

errflag = 0
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Select
While Err.Number <> 0 And errflag < 10
    Err.Number = 0
    Application.Speech.Speak "runtime 2"
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Select
    errflag = errflag + 1
Wend
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: _Note:_ This doesn't appear to be an answer, but as this question hasn't been answered yet, and this answer provides additional information which might help the community isolate the problem, it seems to qualify as a _partial answer_: "Help us find a solution by researching the problem, then contribute the results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried as a partial answer. That way, even if we can’t figure it out, the next person has more to go on." ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)).

Answer (score 0):

Finally!  The answer has been found by my companies IT professional.  This issue has nothing to do with the actual VBA code chosen, the problem comes when Windows is managing the virtual memory.  Office 2016 is a memory hog and the allocated virtual memory was not high enough.  The problem completely goes away when on a machine with 16GB of memory the VM settings are manually changed to Custom size, Initial size=24000 and Maximum size=48000.  Apparently when moving/resizing graphs and/or pictures there is a lot of memory being used, and the default setting of "Automatically manage paging file size for all drives" is just NOT the correct setting.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off the clipboard function will help to resolve the problem:

[image]